# Time Tracking - JavaScript (inc jQuery) or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to track time?

I'm looking to possibly have user accounts who can track time (just a start and stop button) but it would be cool if you could close the tab / browser and come back later and the timer is still going.

If that isn't easy to build, I'd like a way to start and stop a clock. Would that be done using PHP, JavaScript (inc jQuery)?

Comment: @Ron - buying a watch comes to mind?

Comment: Asking such a question indicates you're not ready for the answer. You've jumped in the deep end, keep learning the basics and you will be able to answer this once you're ready as you most likely wouldn't be able to implement the answer even if we gave you it (yet).

Comment: I am ready for the answer plus I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want it to be persistent, then yeah you can use javascript. I won't show you how - there's nothing unique or special about your question, and Google will return 18,500,000 results so I'm sure you know how to use that.

If you want it to be persistent, I can imagine something like this:

1. Store the start time in database associated with the user (or a cookie in the users browser)
2. Start a JS timer based on that start time
3. When window is reopened, retrieve the start time from the database or cookie
4. Start a JS timer based on that start time